# TypeScript Class Generics instance infer never

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
interface TreeRaw {
  ID: string;
  parentID: string;
  seq: number;
  [props: string]: any;
}

class Tree<T extends TreeRaw = TreeRaw> {
  data: T[];

  constructor(rawData: T[]) {
    this.data = rawData;
}

const tree = new Tree([]);
```

[tree infer Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Q9J.png)

why instance tree infer `Tree<never>` instead of `Tree<TreeRaw>`?

what can i do to get instance infer `Tree<TreeRaw>` when i don't enter generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because empty array is always infered to `never[]` by the default. This is because TS does not know whether you want an array of numbers or array of strings or any other array type.

If you want to infer it properly, you should provide explicit generic argument.

```js
interface TreeRaw {
    ID: string;
    parentID: string;
    seq: number;
    [props: string]: any;
}

class Tree<T extends TreeRaw = TreeRaw> {
    data: T[];

    constructor(rawData: T[]) {
        this.data = rawData;
    }
}

// explicit generic argument
const tree = new Tree<TreeRaw>([]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpQhASnA7sgbwChlTkBJAEQC5kBnMKUAcwG4SyAHODcK2hkxBsOpOhACOtEAFcAtgCNo7MsgDanKAHtOdAYxYBdWnBABPdgF8iRBABs4dOmgwQAPKmQQAHpBAATZ3RMHHwAXhcQvAA%20QlFkfzgwOFpUNUN2eIQtEEEZBDAtKAAKKDxKJJS0dIBKONVVMAALYDoAOkTk5Aiy3ArklTJra1schmRGTG7kEAh8YPcF0Oji2tYgA)

Similar example:

```js
const set = new Set([]) // Set<never>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because an empty array (`[]`) cannot be inferred as `TreeRaw[]`.

This one will infer it correctly

```
const tree = new Tree([] as TreeRaw[]);
```